# Serve multiple web requests in Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, nginx, uwsgi

I am using Django with Nginx and want to serve multiple requests in parallel. 
We have Docker configuration and one pod has 10 cores. I am trying to create multiple workers in uWSGI like `(uwsgi --socket /tmp/main.sock --module main.wsgi --enable-threads --master --processes=10 --threads=1 --chmod-socket=666)`
Request first lands to view and from there it calls service file which does heavy work.
Actually, I am using openCV library in service file which has loop over all pixels to remove colored ones(pretty time consuming..)

I also tried using multiple cores and 1 worker as
`(uwsgi --socket /tmp/main.sock --module main.wsgi --enable-threads --master --processes=1 --threads=10 --chmod-socket=666)`. 
But still performance did not improve. I think it is due to GIL which is getting acquired while doing heavy I/O operations, not sure how I can find a work around it. Or use all cores in some other efficient way? TIA!

Comment: But that said, 1 worker will have 10 cores assigned, so total 100 cores needed, will it not starve workers ? Please let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: Yeah, you're right....don't take my advice lol. Its weird that `--processes=10` doesn't work for you though

Comment: Lol, np. So earlier I tested with two requests, they both lands in View.py at same time but when I call Service.py to do image processing stuff(loop over every pixel - time consuming), only one request does it while other waits for it to finish.I am assuming some how cores are not able to do CPU-bound operations in parallel